# Uncaught Error: Class "PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet" not found

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet, phpoffice-phpspreadsheet

Getting started with PHP using phpSpredsheet.  Testing basic code returns the error Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet" not found.  The composer.json file includes:

```
"require": {
    "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.29"
},
```

The path to the files: .\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet

The below php script in Visual Studio appears to pickup the references to Speadsheet and Xlsx, as a mouseover provides tooltip information.

```
// require_once('vendor/autoload.php');
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use phpoffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

// Creates New Spreadsheet
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();

// Retrieve the current active worksheet
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

// Set the value of cell A1
$sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'This is a test!');

// Sets the value of cell B1
$sheet->setCellValue('B1', 'This is only a test');

// Write an .xlsx file
$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);

// Save .xlsx file to the current directory
$writer->save('/test.xlsx');
```

Remark out open_basedir
Restart IIS
Remove ./vendor
Remove ./composer.lock
Reinstall Composer

Comment: Is the `require_once()` really commented out in your code?

Comment: Without the autoloader it won't find the class. Uncomment the first line.

Comment: OMG, that was a stupid mistake.  Thank you for pointing that out.  It was left after commenting out all php code to test resolution of HTML on the page.  But I am back to the error when opening the page after removing the comment on autoload: 

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "phpoffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx" not found

Comment: The second `use` statement should be `use PhpOffice\...`, not `use phpoffice\...`.